# Where satoshi sent by free bitcoin faucets deposited /parked?

Tags: wallet

I am earning and free bitcoin faucets say that they are sending satoshi to my bitcoin address or to some micro wallets like https://faucetbox.com or Paytoshi.com. The said micro wallets in turn send them automatically when the pre-fixed threshold limit is reached.  I have two questions and seek your guidance.

(1) I do not know how to see my accumulated satoshi earnings because I do not know where they are parked.  Can you guide me in this respect?

(2) How to send/transfer them to my Blockchain Wallet Account?

I look forward to your able guidance....

regards

Dr. Surya NSK

Answer (score 0):

Go to faucetbox.com and enter your address in the address checker (starting with 1xxx.../3xxx...) there. 
It will allow you to set the payout threshold and see how much you've accumulated. Microwallets are used to avoid transaction fees every time you earn a few satoshis.
Hope it helps.